# processReleaseResources in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, apk

While creating APK in flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-osx Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

please help me to resolve this issue